# How to execute renderURL in aui script or javascript in Liferay

Tags: jquery, liferay, liferay-6, alloy-ui, liferay-aui

I have come across a scenario where I am required to use renderURL in javascript.
I have a aui-datatable with many rows of data. Upon clicking of any row, I need to call a render URL to load the next view.

Generally, I used to make use of renderURL in case of buttons by writing the renderURL in the onClick event. i.e,

aui:button name="TestButton" onClick="<%=testRenderURL.toString()%>"

But in the current scenario, the control will be in the delegate function of my datatable i.e, click handler function which is:-

```
Y.delegate('click', function(e) {
var target = e.currentTarget;
record = this.get('recordset').getRecord(target.get('id')).getValue();
alert(record.name);
  //HERE I NEED TO CALL RENDER URL AND LOAD NEXT JSP PAGE
  // after fetching current row values. i.e, send record.name to next jsp file
}, '#myTable', 'tr', dt);
```

Comment: you may dynamically create anchor tag, attach url to it, and simulate click event on anchor tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    AUI().use('liferay-portlet-url', function(A) {
      var url=Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
      url.setPortletId('currentPortletId');
      url.setParameter('name','value');
      A.one(document.createElement('a')).attr('href',url).simulate('click');
   })
```

The code above would be helpful to you to achieve your requirement. Put it in click event handler function of row of your data-table.

NOTE: Just replace currentPortletId, name and value in above code as per your requirement, you may also load 'liferay-portlet-url' module separately.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, I will try it and keep you posted

Comment: Infact, I am required to load another JSP page in a tabbed view. So, I made used of  ajax call...    div.plug(A.Plugin.IO, {
                                                                      uri: renderUrl.toString(),
                                                                  parseContent: true
                                                              }).render();

Answer (score 3):

This could be of help. I implemented it using Liferay 6.1.2. I wanted to generate a PortletURL (a RenderURL in my case) depending of the button clicked, using Javascript.  What I did in my JSP file was the following:

1) I had four buttons:

```
<aui:button value="Button 1" name="button1" 
    onClick='<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() + "getButtonId(1);"%>'/>

<aui:button value="Button 2" name="button2" 
    onClick='<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() + "getButtonId(2);"%>'/>

<aui:button value="Button 3" name="button3" 
    onClick='<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() + "getButtonId(3);"%>'/>

<aui:button value="Button 4" name="button4" 
    onClick='<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() + "getButtonId(4);"%>'/>
```

2) I generated the PortletURL using Javascript and then set the new JSP page that wanted to forward to afterwards:

```
<aui:script use="liferay-portlet-url">
Liferay.provide(
  window,
  '<portlet:namespace/>getButtonId',
  function(id) {
    var renderURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
    renderURL .setPortletMode("view");
    renderURL .setWindowState("normal");
    renderURL .setPortletId("myPortletId");
    renderURL.setParameter("page","new_jsp_page");
    renderURL.setParameter("buttonId",id);

    window.location.href = renderURL.toString();
   }
  );
</aui:script>
```

This could be applied to the situation where there are many rows generated depending on the data retrieved from a database.